# How do i get the input content that follows the rake command

Tags: ruby, rake

all.
How do i get the content that follows the rake command ,

for example, when i type this command in terminal `# rake make_file myfile` so that it will creates a file named myfile.txt, how do i write this rake task ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake task_name some_param` will actually try to fire two rake tasks: `task_name` and `some_param` unless the parameters are in the format of `param=value`, in which case the parameter is populated in the `ENV` constant.

So, `rake task_name myfile=/some/file` can be read from `ENV["myfile"]`.

Comment: So, how do i know the ENV["myfile"] whether existing ?

Comment: Good anwser is here [link](http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html)